# Understanding Chrome "Other Bookmarks" Folder

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

When I add a bookmark in Chrome, it gives me an "Other bookmarks" folder option to store it in.

This is baffling.  A folder called "other" begs the question "other than what?"

Is there some special behavior for this "Other" folder?  What quality does it have that endows it with "other-ness"?

Comment: It is the new Bookmarking System of Chrome, I dont know it features but probably you can disable it by typing this " chrome://flags/#enhanced-bookmarks-experiment "  into your address bar  and then disable it. 

Check this link too : 

http://www.pcworld.com/article/240975/remove_the_other_bookmarks_folder_from_google_chrome.html

Answer (score 1):

That is simply the folder for any bookmarks which you have not classified into a folder yourself (such as mobile or bookmarks toolbar or any other specific folder). You can choose this as an option if you just want to save the bookmark with no classification.
[The folder can be removed from your Bookmarks bar by emptying it](https://www.pcworld.com/article/240975/remove_the_other_bookmarks_folder_from_google_chrome.html). As far as I remember though, the "Other Bookmarks" folder was present in the old bookmark system though.

Comment: This explanation doesn't make sense because I cannot make any bookmark folder that is a sibling of the "Other" folder.  I am only permitted to make folders under "Mobile" or "Other."  I'm forced to classify everything in the galaxy as "Moble" or "Other".  Doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 1):

The "Other Bookmarks" makes sense when you understand that it is where you can put bookmarks that you don't want to see on the Bookmarks Bar. Let me explain.

The Bookmarks Bar is like an accordion. If you only have a few items it can be short, with everything visible on screen, or it can extend offscreen into the ">>" overflow zone. You can drag and drop items anywhere along the accordion. If your visible area is full and you insert another item into the visible area, the last visible item will slide into the ">>". Likewise, if you move or delete something from the visible area, the next ">>" item(s) can slide back into view (depending on the character length of the item labels).

Now, imagine you have an item towards the end of your accordion called "My Secrets", which is offscreen in the ">>" zone. And then imagine you remove some items from the visible area, and without you noticing, "My Secrets" has slid on screen. *That* is a reason for the "Other Bookmarks" folder, i.e. a place where you can put bookmarks that you don't want to see on the Bookmarks Bar.